# CentOS 5/Apache Subdomain not pointing to correct DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I set up my subdomain with my registrar of "test" point to my server ip. Everything connects and the subdomain works, but it's pointing to /var/www/html instead of /var/www/test

I restarted apache and checked the logs. I'm confused:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.example.com
    ServerAlias test.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/test/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that this has it's own conf file and the permissions are correct for /var/www/test - I also put in an index.php with dummy text to check it. No luck

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Should I put this in httpd.conf rather than it's own conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only put this in its own `.conf` file if `httpd.conf` is including it.

Firstly, start by putting it at the bottom of your `httpd.conf`, that'll ensure you at least have the right one.

Once it works, you can see what directory apache includes by looking for an `Include` directive. If there isn't one, add it. There should be one like `Include conf.d/*.conf` - this means you can put it in your `conf.d` folder and as long as it has an extension of `.conf`, it'll be included by `httpd.conf`.

Note that you will need to have [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) in order to use `<VirtualHost>`s.